# SQLite cannot open file. Failed to open database

Tags: android, database, flutter, sqlite

I'm having trouble opening a database with my pre-made arrays. The database contains 4 tables for reading and displaying information.

Flutter dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  path_provider: ^2.0.2
  sqflite: ^2.2.6
  toast: ^0.2.9
  overlay_support: ^2.1.0
  intl: ^0.18.1
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
```

My dbHelper:

```
class InwentaryzacjDbHelper {
  static final _directoryPath = '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/';
  static final _databaseName = 'InwentaryzacjaDane.db';
  static Database? _db;

  Future<Database?> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = await initDB();
    return _db;
  }

  initDB() async {
    try {
      if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
        io.Directory? dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String path = join(dir!.path, _directoryPath, _databaseName);
        io.File file = io.File(path);
        var theDB = await openDatabase(path, version: 1);
        print("Znaleziono bazę danych");
        return theDB;
      } else {
        throw Exception("Storage permission not granted");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("Błąd inicjalizacji bazy danych: $e");
      rethrow;
    }
```

My Error:

```
E/SQLiteLog( 7986): (14) cannot open file at line 38589 of [b2325a6e1c]
E/SQLiteLog( 7986): (14) os_unix.c:38589: (13) open(/storage/emulated/0/Documents/InwentaryzacjaDane.db) -
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7986): Failed to open database '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/InwentaryzacjaDane.db'.
E/SQLiteDatabase( 7986): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: Cannot open database '/storage/emulated/0/Documents/InwentaryzacjaDane.db': File /storage/emulated/0/Documents/InwentaryzacjaDane.db is not readable
```

How can i solve this problem?? The database file must be in the path. "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/" Or, " sdcard/Documents"

I already add permission on my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And i allowed them using simple button

```
onPressed: () async {
                        PermissionStatus _permisionStatus =
                            await Permission.storage.request();
                        if (_permisionStatus == PermissionStatus.granted) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text("Permission storage")));
                        }

                        if (_permisionStatus == PermissionStatus.denied) {
                          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                              const SnackBar(
                                  content:
                                      Text("This permisison is recommended")));
                        }
                        if (_permisionStatus ==
                            PermissionStatus.permanentlyDenied) {
                          openAppSettings();
                        }
                      },
                    )),
```

The error only doesn't appear when the path is "/data/data/com.example.mininventory/databases" But it is the path from Android Emulator (Pixel 3 Emulator). But this path cannot be because it is hidden to another user. And I must have access to the file after connecting the phone via a usb cable and uploading the database to the storage or sdcard directory.

Comment: Is your app checking if the file exists? After that, is your app checking if the file can be read? (With File.canRead()?). Apps on Android 11+ devices cannot read files you uploaded by usb cable.

Comment: So I can't read the database file after uploading it to e.g. sdcart? No way ? 
I added to allow access to files...

Comment: You cannot read the file in the classic way. But you can use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user pick the file and then open an InputStream for the obtained uri and read from the stream as usual.